# Why does this formula yield a clockwise rotation for curves defined by a cartesian equation, and a counterclockwise rotation in parametric form?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, rotations

Here is the reasoning I've attemped in order to espablish a formula for the ***counterclockwise*** rotation of a curve.

Let $M=(x,y)$ be any point on the plane, associated with a cartesian coordinate system $<0, \vec { i}, \vec{j}>$.

The position vector of ths point is $\vec {OM} = \vec A+ \vec B= x\vec { i} + y \vec{j} $

Rotating point $M$ counterclockwise by a positve angle $\alpha$ amounts to rotate counterclockwise  the components of its postion vector by the same angle.

So , with $M'$ the image of $M$ under ths rotation, we will have :

$\vec {OM'} = \vec {A'}+\vec {B'}$ with  $\vec {A'}$, the image of $\vec {A}$ and $\vec {B'}$ , the image of vector $\vec {B}$.

Now ,

$\vec {A'}= x cos (\alpha) \vec i + x sin (\alpha) \vec j$.

$\vec {B'}= y cos (\alpha + \pi /2) \vec i + x sin (\alpha+ \pi/2) \vec j $

$= y ( - sin (\alpha) )\vec i + x cos(\alpha) \vec j$

$= -y  sin (\alpha) )\vec i + x cos(\alpha)\vec j$.

Therefore ,

$\vec{OM'} =  \vec {A'} + \vec {B'} = \Large{[} x cos (\alpha) - y  sin (\alpha)\Large{]} \vec i + \Large{[}x sin( \alpha) + y cos(\alpha)\Large{]} \vec j$,

implying that

$M' = (x cos (\alpha) - y  sin (\alpha) , x sin( \alpha) + y cos(\alpha))$.

My problem is that :

(1) when I apply this reasoning to a parametric curve, it seems to work , that is, if I have a curve $C= < f(t), g(t)> $ and ask for

$$C' = <f(t) cos (\alpha) - g(t)  sin (\alpha) , f(t) sin( \alpha) + g(t) cos(\alpha)>$$

what I get is that  $C'$ rotates counterclockwise, as desired.

Example with $\alpha = 2 $ rd: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/daaouk87yw

(2) but if I substitute the coordinates of a generic $M'$ point in a cartesian " $x-y$" equation, ***the curve rotates clockwise***.

Example : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vm5pbtxzge

I'm sure some confusion prevents me from understanding what is happening, but I can't manage to see which one.

Comment: Nice examples! I've noticed this effect rather inadvertently too. It's been a few years so I don't remember what my conclusion was or if I even found one. I think there's something rather subtle that can be said here. I'll ponder and get back to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll compare the two operations you describe. Instead of reasoning with coordinates, let's use directly the point $M$, and the operation $R$ applied to $M$. $R$ can be a rotation, or any other bijective function.

- In the first case, you directly change the parametric equation $M = F(t)$ that expresses $M$ according to some parameter $t$. This becomes $M' = R \circ F (t)$.
- In the second case, you transform the usage of $M$ coordinates in an equation they verify. If the equation is $E(M) = 0$, it becomes $E(R(M''))=0$.

$R$ being bijective, $E(R(M''))=0$ is equivalent to $M=R(M'')$.
While in the first case $M'=R(M)$.
We can see the role of $R$ is reversed; hence what you remarked: if you express $M''=S(M)$, we see that $S=R^{-1}$.

This is very intuitive, in fact. Let's say it with a scaling operation; compare:

- "I'll give you twice the amount $M$".
- "The amount I'll give you is such that, when multiplied by two, it is the same as $M$".

Another similar situation happens when transforming a vector, versus transforming the vector base: that's [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors).

Comment: Thanks for this answer Jean-Armand. I think 'm not far from understanding. One thing I do not get is the use of $M''$ . What does ths symbol denote? Should I understand  " the image of the mage of M under the R transformation"?   I'm specially referiing to this sentence : " if the equation is E(M)=0, it becomes E(R(M′′))=0. "

Comment: @VinceVickler Oh, $M''$ is just another point. I called it like that because you used $M'$. More precisely, $M''$ is the ante-image of $M$ by $R$ (a bijection), i.e. $M=R(M'')$.

Comment: @VinceVickler Note that the last example, about vector and base, is a little far-fetched. It displays the same phenomenon, but the cause is not exactly the same (it could probably be presented as to be the same cause, but that would obscure rather than enlighten). I mentioned it only to introduce the covariance/contravariance concept, which is very widespread - even present in programming languages for example.

Comment: Another place where a similar phenomenon crops up -- although here also I am not sure whether this enlightens or confuses -- is in the way you can change a function in order to move its graph up, down, left, or right. Namely, starting with the graph of $y=f(x)$, you can move it up three units in the obvious way: add $3$ to the function output, so $y=f(x)+3$. But if you want to move it three units to the right (increasing the $x$ coordinate of every point), you must **subtract** $3$ from the function input: $y=f(x-3).$

Comment: @DavidK That's actually what happens with covariance/contravariance in programming languages (although there it deals with data _types_, not data values): a function is contravariant in its inputs types, and covariant in its output type. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types

Answer (score 3):

Okay I think if you write things in the notation of matrices it becomes a little easier to see what's happening. So we're going to use only the position vectors $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ to represent the terminal point (x,y). And then we can think of counterclockwise rotation around the origin by angle $\alpha$ as applying the rotation matrix

$R=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha &  \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix}$

So $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ rotated by $\alpha$ is

$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha &  \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\cos \alpha  -y\sin \alpha  \\
x\sin \alpha  +y\cos \alpha
\end{bmatrix}$

which agrees with the formulas you gave.

Now lets consider rotating a set of vectors defined parameterically
$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mid x=f(t), y=g(t)\right\}$ by $\alpha$. The resulting set will be just multiplying each set by $R$, that is $\left\{R\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\mid x=f(t), y=g(t)\right\}$

If we do the same for a set of vectors defined implicitly
$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mid f(x,y)=0\right\}$
multiplying by $R$ still works
$\left\{R\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mid f(x,y)=0\right\}$

However you are looking for a *new* function $F(x,y)$ such that the set of rotated points is
$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mid F(x,y)=0\right\}$

**Edit:**

Okay to see why this is not the same thing it may be worth referring to these new rotated variables by a different notation. Let's use capital letters to define the rotated coordinates:

$\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}=R \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x\cos \alpha  -y\sin \alpha  \\
x\sin \alpha  +y\cos \alpha
\end{bmatrix}$

So to summarize you start with a set defined:

$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mid f(x,y)=0\right\}$ where you could take $f(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{5^2}+\frac{x^2}{3^2}-1$ to get an ellipse like your original examples.

and you want to convert to a set defined by:

$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \mid F(X,Y)=0\right\}$.

It would be nice to use the original function $f(x,y)$ to define the relationship but it only works for the unrotated vectors. So that means you need a way to go from the rotated vectors $\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$ to the unrotated vectors $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ in order to put in your $f(x,y)$ to see if they match they satisfy $f(x,y)=0$.

Since $\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}=R \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$, you can apply the inverse to get $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=R^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$. Naturally the inverse of a rotation is simply rotating by the same amount in the opposite direction. So the expression you would plug into the original defining equation would be rotated in the opposite direction of the rotation of the points.

Comment: I'm ok with elementary marices operations and with the matrix - vector product. But I'm getting lost in the answer.  For example, why turning the relation that defines the ellipse  into a function, and a multivariable one?  Also, why is this mutivariable function $f(x,y)$  set at $0$?

Comment: However, thanks for the time taken to enlighten this question!

Comment: Sorry about multiple edits, I accidentally submitted too soon. Setting f(x,y)=0 is just a generic way of describing an equation in multiple variables. Your example $y^2/5^2+x^2/3^2=1$ can be defined in this way by moving the constant over to the other side too $f(x,y)=y^2/5^2+x^2/3^2-1$. Then $f(x,y)=0$ is equivalent to your equation.

Comment: I'd say focus on the difference between changing the equation and rotating the points that are a solution set to the equation. Changing the variables in the equation is not the same thing as changing the solution set (in fact they are inverses of each other).

Comment: The distinction is useful, thanks!

Comment: Glad it's helped. I'm not entirely satisfied with my explanation. If I think of a better way of explaining this relation I'll come back and edit some more.

Comment: @VinceVickler I've made an attempt to clarify that last step in the answer a little. Let me know if it helps :)